# Print a name of a list within a list

Tags: python, list

Hello I am trying to print the name of a list within a list. I have tried the following but all I can do is print the value of the list within a list. Not the name of the list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2]
list3 = [1,2,3,4]
lists = [list1,list2,list3]

for x in lists:
  if len(x) == 4:
  print (x)
```

Comment: Elements of a list don't have names, they have positions.

Comment: A list has no fixed name, because you can assign its name to anything. Its unclear from your question, what you are asking.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It seems quite clear that he is looking for a dictionary or key/value structure, where he can get the names of the keys.

Comment: @Kjartan I'm afraid it is not clear unless explicitly mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac He clearly asks for "_the name of an element (which happens to be a list) in a list_". Sounds like asking for a dictionary to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `dictionary` here:

```
>>> dic = {'list1': range(1, 4), 'list2':range(1, 3), 'list3':range(1, 5)}
>>> for k, v in dic.items():
...     if len(v) == 4:
...         print k
...         
list3
```

Using `lists = [list1,list2,list3]` won't work here because this assignment simply creates new references to the three list objects.

```
>>> lists[0] is list1
True
```

So, the object `[1,2,3]` has now two references `list1` and `lists[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do but with not lists. You may better use dict [dictinary]. A dictionary is one which is hash structure in python with keys and values associated to keys. making them key-values pairs.
Usually lists would be like

```
d = {'one':1,'two':2}
```

which can be accessed like print d[one] which prints '1';

For your case, we can use the same dict as...

```
d = {'list1': list1,'list2': list2,'list3': list3}
```

which when called like print d[list1] prints all the elements of the list1. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. 
You might want to consider using a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and using the name as key and setting the list as value.